# Trouble with MESA SDK setup: Missing prerequisites for mesasdk_init.sh

Tags: shell-script, software-installation

I am facing an issue while trying to set up the MESA SDK on my system. When I run the command:

```bash
source $MESASDK_ROOT/bin/mesasdk_init.sh
```

I encounter the following error:

```
mesasdk_init.sh: checking prerequisites
mesasdk_init.sh: missing prerequisites:
  C shell
```

I have already installed the C shell, but it seems like there might be an issue with the configuration. Can anyone guide me on how to resolve this problem? I appreciate any assistance or suggestions.

Additional Information:

```bash
>uname -a
Linux morbid-Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBD 6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 10:53:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```bash
>gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/home/morbid/mesasdk/bin/gfortran.exec
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/morbid/mesasdk/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/user/sdk2-tmp/build/gcc/configure CC= CXX= --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/user/sdk2-tmp/mesasdk --with-gmp=/home/user/sdk2-tmp/mesasdk --with-mpfr=/home/user/sdk2-tmp/mesasdk --with-mpc=/home/user/sdk2-tmp/mesasdk --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-libsanitizer --enable-clocale=generic
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 13.1.0 (GCC)
```

```bash
>echo $MESASDK_ROOT
/home/morbid/mesasdk
```

```bash
>echo $PATH
/home/morbid/mesasdk/bin:/home/morbid/mesasdk/bin:/home/morbid/mesasdk/bin:/home/morbid/mesasdk/bin:/home/morbid/mesasdk/bin:/home/morbid/mesasdk/bin:/home/morbid/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Which C shell did you install, and how exactly?

Comment: hi, I installed the latest version 20110502 of C shell (csh) and installed it using the terminal by running the following command: sudo apt-get install csh. Thanks for your answer friend.

Comment: it looks like it may require the Tenex C shell - `sudo apt install tcsh`

Comment: Thank you brother for your collaboration, I did what you suggested and the problem was solved.